# PHP array syntax: array(...) or [...]

Tags: php, arrays, syntax

In PHP, are these identical? `$x = [1,2,3];` and `$x = array(1,2,3);`

Are there cases where these two methods of creating an array differ?

Is there any reason to use one over the other?

Comment: Depends on the PHP version.

Comment: Please give a reason for your downvotes in the comments.

Comment: Wasn't me, if you're asking => me. Probably because this was a Google'able question? I'll get all notices in this thread by you commenting till somebody else joins in ;)

Comment: I didn't think anyone would downvote a question because the answer depended on the PHP version.

Comment: People can be rather *strange animals* at times ;)

Comment: Question edited. "which is preferred" does not mean "which do you like better" - this was never opinion based.

Comment: I'm sure there's an underlying reason for it Jake. I for one can't answer that because I don't know it (I just know that it's related to the version of PHP), and it would require a bit of time in order for me to research it in further detail; something you could probably do, or ask AbraCadaver.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59686/discussion-between-jake-and-fred-ii).

Comment: You got +1. Good point. I had same question today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are identical with the caveat that `$x = [1,2,3];` requires PHP >= 5.4.0.

Comment: I would simply add that the reason people get confused is that `array()` looks like a function, when it's really just a [language construct](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)

Comment: That explains why I can do `'a'=>'b'` inside `array()` but not other functions.

Comment: If the function arg is an array you can do `['a'=>'b']`.